# How many faces are in this tree?

Tags: the-witness

[image]

This is the tree above the Quarry, just outside of the Desert area. So far I've seen three different faces, yet I get the distinct feeling there's more. I've tried all sorts of viewing angles running around the tree and can't seem to find anymore.

How many faces are actually visible on this tree?

Comment: I only know of four, the fourth being the grumpy bearded old man embedded in the trunk in that picture.  A lot of people consider that one [pareidolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareidolia), though.

Comment: Grumpy bearded old man? Can't say I'm really seeing it -- I've tried looking at it from all angles and I can't tell where the bearded old man is supposed to be.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/8h0pTNL.png

Comment: Also, final ending spoilers highly-related to this question: https://www.reddit.com/r/TheWitness/comments/47mt4t/